# Wifi Problem With Elementary OS

Tags: wifi

I am a noob at linux so don't be harsh please. I installed Elementary OS on my Dell Inspiron 7559 and the install was fine but, wifi networks don't show up and ethernet works perfectly fine. Can someone help me out please.

Answer (score 1):

Your wireless card is not supported by the 3.19 kernel.

To upgrade the kernel, run this command

> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial
>   xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial
>   xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial
>   libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial

Reboot your computer and try connecting to the Wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with every Linux distribution on my Asus X552 and the only solution I found is to put laptop on sleep and then turn it on again and wifi will work.